# Python Kivy: Update Label

Tags: python, kivy

i am new in the Kivy Topic and i have got a simple question (i think).

With the function "zufall" i create a random number.
This number should update every 2 seconds in the label.

But when i am running the code, the error "Label.text accept only str" occurs.
But from my opinion i made the "random_number" to a string. Or is there another problem, with my thinking?

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import random
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class ConnectPage(GridLayout):
    # runs on initialization
    def zufall(self, *args):

        random_number = random.randrange(10)
        random_number = str(random_number)
        print(random_number)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2  # used for our grid
        self.add_widget(Label(text='OEE'))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=self.zufall))



class EpicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        t = ConnectPage()
        Clock.schedule_interval(t.zufall, 2)
        return t


if __name__ == "__main__":
    EpicApp().run()
```

Can someone of you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to `return` your random number from your `zufall` function, and call that function from your `__init__` like this:

```
    # runs on initialization
    def zufall(self, *args):
        random_number = random.randrange(10)
        random_number = str(random_number)
        return random_number

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2  # used for our grid
        self.add_widget(Label(text='OEE'))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=self.zufall()))
```

Comment: @Julian If you found my answer helpful, then you might consider to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so other people see it too.. ;o)