# bind, text of label in kv file to a method in python file

Tags: python-3.x, text, label, kivy, kivy-language

I want to bind a function in .kv file to a method in .py file in simple words I want to update quotes every day on the main screen of my app so I used screen widget to display the quotes so how do I bind the label.text to a method in .py file
here's the class of .py file I want to bind

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def quote(self):
        self.quote.text = 'I often think that the night is more alive and more richly colored than 
                             the day. - Vincent van Gogh'
```

here's the root widget of .kv file

```
    <MainScreen>:
        story: story

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Label:
            id: story
            text: root.quote
            font_size: '20sp'
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'x': -0.2, 'y': 0.27}
```

but it showing error saying label.text must be string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Kivy: Update Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60851369/python-kivy-update-label)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a kivy `Property`, and using the `quote()` method to update that `Property`. Here is a way to do that in your code:

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    quote_text = StringProperty('Not Set')

    def quote(self, *args):
        self.quote_text = 'I often think that the night is more alive and more richly colored than  the day. - Vincent van Gogh'
```

The `quote_text` is a `StringProperty` that can be referenced in the `kv` and the `quote` method now updates that `StringProperty`.

And in your `kv`:

```
<MainScreen>:
    story: story

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Label:
        id: story
        text: root.quote_text
        font_size: '20sp'
        size: self.texture_size
        pos_hint: {'x': -0.2, 'y': 0.27}
```

Then, calling the `quote()` method will update the `Label` text. To test it, you can use a `build()` method of your `App` as:

```
def build(self):
    main = MainScreen()
    Clock.schedule_once(main.quote, 5)
    return main
```

Comment: can you explain it more bcoz I tried this and it showed only "Not Set" on the screen which I passed in StringProperty()

Comment: Look carefully at my answer and note wherever you see `quote_text`. Make sure that your code has those same changes.

Comment: if I return main in my mdapp class my styling doesn't appear then

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on without seeing more of your code. That is why we usually ask you to post a [mcve].